# Exception has occurred. EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) using C and SDL

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, sdl

I am getting a EXP_BAD_ACCESS error while trying to assign a SDL_TEXTURE* to another SDL_TEXTURE* using a fucntion.

I am compiling using clang on macOS Sonoma 14.1 using VSCode.

I have tried allocating memory to fps_texture->texture using malloc, but that resulted in the same error.

in main.c

```c
GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture = NULL;
fps_texture->texture = text_load(app.renderer, fps_font, "TEST"); // Getting error here
if (!fps_texture->texture)
{
   printf("Unable to load font into texture!\n");
}
```

text_load definition

```c
SDL_Texture* text_load(SDL_Renderer* renderer, TTF_Font* font, char* text)
{
  SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;

  //Render text surface
  SDL_Surface* text_surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text, TEXT_COLOR);
  if (text_surface == NULL)
  {
    printf( "Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
  }
  else
  {
    //Create texture from surface pixels
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, text_surface);
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
      printf( "Unable to create texture from rendered text! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
      //Get image dimensions
      // text_texture->width = text_surface->w;
      // text_texture->height = text_surface->h;
    }

    //Get rid of old surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(text_surface);
  }
  
  return texture;
}
```

struct definition

```c
typedef struct GAME_TEXTURE
{
  SDL_Texture* texture;
  uint32_t width;
  uint32_t height;
} GAME_TEXTURE;
```

tasks.json

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-g",
        "main.c",
        "-I",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.26.5/include/SDL2",
        "-I",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.6.3_1/include/SDL2",
        "-I",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.20.2/include/SDL2",
        "-L",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.26.5/lib",
        "-L",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_image/2.6.3_1/lib",
        "-L",
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2_ttf/2.20.2/lib/",
        "-l",
        "SDl2",
        "-l",
        "SDL2_image",
        "-l",
        "SDL2_ttf",
        "-o",
        "main"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    },
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "args": [
        "-fcolor-diagnostics",
        "-fansi-escape-codes",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ]
}
```

Why can't the memory be accessed?

Comment: `GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture = NULL;` directly followed by `fps_texture->texture = ...`? The pointer variable `fps_texture` doesn't point anywhere, it's `NULL`. You can't dereference that pointer variable. When you do, you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As user Some programmer dude wrote above, you might need to initialize `GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture` using `malloc` first, before doing anything else. Not writing this as an answer because I cannot test it on my machine right now.

Comment: I have got it working now by allocating the GAME_TEXTURE* itself instead of the pointer inside of it: GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture = (GAME_TEXTURE*)malloc(sizeof(GAME_TEXTURE));   This also works btw: GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture = new GAME_TEXTURE;     Thanks!

Comment: @Flipmode34 Since you say _"This also works btw: `GAME_TEXTURE* fps_texture = new GAME_TEXTURE;`"_ , you are not actually programming in C. You are either programming in C++ or some other language where you can use `new` to create objects. C is not one of them. Oh, I see, `/usr/bin/clang++` and `-std=c++17` - so definitely C++.

Comment: You don't have to `typedef` your classes in C++. Just make it `struct GAME_TEXTURE { ... };`

Comment: Yes, I was not helping myself, because I was compiling using clang++ instead of clang. I now compile just using clang. And then of course the 'new' keyword is not valid anymore. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You could stay with C++ if you haven't had problems so far. In C++ you can make objects deal with their own resources. `GAME_TEXTURE` could load the `SDL_Texture` automatically on creation etc.

Comment: In both C and C++ there's no need (that I can see) to dynamically allocate `fps_texture` (using `malloc` or `new`). Just define it as an object directly: `GAME_TEXTURE fps_texture;`